# Lego Education 9594 instructions for models

Tags: instructions, education

Recently at work, I found boxes of the Lego Education Green City Challenge 9594, but there are no instructions to build the models for each challenge. I was able to go online and find the instructions for the center piece model but not the others. I would like help in finding those instructions. I have emailed LEGO Education and their response is that the set is so old they do not have it (the set came out in 2011).

Comment: Related: [How can I complete the build of this Lunar lander from the Space and Airport Set (9335)?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/15381/13308)

Answer (score 3):

The instructions for the "LEGO NXT Green City Challenge Activity 9594" seem to be on CDROM only.

Replacement disks are offered on bricklink for [Green City Challenge Activity Pack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=2009594&idColor=0#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) and [Mindstorms Education NXT Software 2.1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=2000080&idColor=0#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

See this post [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/how-can-i-get-a-replacement-of-lego-nxt-green-city-challenge-activity-pack-cd-ro) for another answer.